# Flex Popup border fragments staying on screen

Tags: apache-flex, popup, border

I have a Flex 4.6 app in which a popup with a white border comes up when the user mouses over an icon.  When the user rolls off the icon or popup, the popup goes away (custom tooltip).  The problem is, sometimes when the popup goes away, some points of the border stay on the screen on either side of the icon (almost like they stained the display).  Has anyone ever seen this?  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Some code might be useful too, especially since your using a custom tooltip. You'll need some more reputation to attach an image, here is an upvote...

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out the problem.  The code that was written to make the popups was not clearing them properly (they still existed with 0 width) which is what caused them to stay on the screen)